# Tate modules of commutative group schemes over finite field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a finite type commutative group scheme over a finite field $k=\Bbb F_q$ with $\Gamma=Gal(\bar k/k)$ and $l$ be a prime such that $(l,q)=1$, we can also define the Tate module $T_lG =\varprojlim_nG[l^n](\bar k)$. Then we can also consider the natural map

$Hom_k(G_1,G_2) \otimes \Bbb Z_l \rightarrow Hom_\Gamma(T_lG_1,T_lG_2)$

for any two commutative group scheme over $k$, or more generally the map

$\text{Ext}^i_k(G_1,G_2) \otimes \Bbb Z_l \rightarrow \text{Ext}^i_\Gamma(T_lG_1,T_lG_2)$ for every natural number $i$ at least when the extension groups are well-defined ([This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26045/ext-of-tate-modules-of-abelian-varieties) may be related).

My first question is: when is this map surjective, injective or an isomorphism? If $G_i$ are abelian varieties and $i=0$, it's well-known that this map is an isomorphism. If $G_2=\Bbb G_m$ and $G_1$ is an abelian variety, this is also true for $i=0$ as both sides are zero, and is true for $i=1$ and $\text{dim}G_1=1$ as $\text{Ext}^1(A,\Bbb G_m)$ is the dual of $A$ and one can compute both sides explicitly (see [this master thesis](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/zhao.pdf)). However, this map can fail to be injective for trivial reasons (For instance, right side could be zero for some finite abelian groups).

So my second question is: how to describe extension groups between commutative group schemes using linear algebra datas in a systematic way? For instance, how to describe extension groups of finite group schemes like $\alpha_p$, $\mu_p$?

The last question is about growth of $\#G[l^n]$ for commutative group schemes (in order to study the Tate module). Let $k$ be any field, $G$ be a commutative group scheme over a field $k$ (not necessarily finite type) and $p$ be a prime. Assume $G[p^n]$ is a finite group scheme for every $n$, does there always exist $C >0,h \geq 0$ such that $\#G[p^n]=Cp^{nh}$ for $n >> 0$? Here the order of a finite group scheme means the dimension of its global section ring. I know the result holds for etale group schemes and abelian varieties. For example, if $G$ is constant i.e an abstract abelian group and $\#G[p^n]$ is finite for every $n$, then we know $G[p^\infty]\cong (\Bbb Q_p/\Bbb Z_p)^h\oplus T$ for some $h \geq 0$ and finite $p$-group $T$ (this result is used when studying Tate-Shafarevich group of elliptic curves).

Edit: there are good theory for commutative linear algebraic groups over complex number, for example every connected one is a product of $\Bbb G_a$ and $\Bbb G_m$, see [here](https://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=16119). [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1123/what-are-the-higher-mathrmextia-mathbfg-ms-where-a-is-an-abelian) is some discussion for higher extension groups. I am more interested in higher extension groups or non-reduced case.

Comment: I know how to answer the last question but not any of the others.

Comment: This seems like a question that is too broad to really be answered in one go. Let me attempt to say some words on 2. You can assume that each $G_i$ is built, via extensions, from building block group schemes. These fall, essentially, into several classes: abelian varieties, tori, smooth unipotent groups, finite etale group schemes, and finite connected group schemes.  To try and uniformly describe extensions for all of these seems unreasonable, and so I think you need to consider them on a case-by-case basis. Let met just mention the specific examples you pointed out of $\alpha_p$ and $\mu_p$.

Comment: These fall into the category of finite connected group schemes. Such objects are tailor built to be handled by Dieudonne theory. So, for example, to compute $\text{Ext}^1(\alpha_p,\alpha_p)$ one really computes $\text{Ext}^1(D(\alpha_p),D(\alpha_p))$ where $D(\alpha_p)$ is the Dieudonne module of $\alpha_p$ which, here, just looks like $\mathbb{F}_p$ with the Frobenius operator 0. So, you're essentially trying to find extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$ by itself that have operators $F$ and $V$ that restriction $0$ on $D(\alpha_p)$ and map to $0$ on $D(\alpha_p)$ and satisfy $FV=VF=0$. I leave it to

Comment: you to figure out what such things look like. In particular, as this example shows for some of the types of group schemes mentioned above $T_\ell$ is a horrible choice since it is essentially tailor made to pick up on etale data of $G$.  If $G$ has no etale data (e.g. it's a connected finite group scheme) is essentially useless. Dieudonne theory is meant to fill the whole there (i.e. in the case of finite connected group schemes).

Comment: @SomeGuy Thank you, I also want to know whether higher extension group vanishes.

Comment: @zzy Do you mind if I ask why?

Comment: As I found my understanding of higher extension groups is weaker than hom. An important case I want to consider is the original tate conjecture with Hom being replaced by Ext. I will not bother you, as I should think by myself.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to answer your last question on the order of $\#G[\ell^n]$ for $(\ell,p) = 1$.

> > **Assumption:** $G$ a commutative connected group scheme locally of finite type over $k$.

Since you're interested in the order of the group scheme $G[\ell^n]$, it is harmless to pass to $k = \overline{k}$ (a connected group scheme locally of finite type over $k$ is geometrically connected). Then $G_{\text{red}}$ is a closed reduced subgroup scheme of $G$ with $G_{\text{red}}[\ell^n] = G[\ell^n]$ as the latter is \'{e}tale over $k$. Therefore we may assume that $G$ is reduced, a fortiori smooth. By [Chevalley's Theorem](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/chev.pdf), we have an exact sequence
$$0 \to H \to G \to A \to 0$$
where $H$ is a closed linear algebraic subgroup and $A$ an abelian variety.

> > **Lemma:** For every $n > 0$, the sequence
> >     $$0 \to H[\ell^n] \to G[\ell^n] \to A[\ell^n] \to 0$$
> >     is still exact.
> >
> > **Proof:** We have to show that $H/\ell^n H = 0$. Since $(\ell,p) = 1$ the multiplication by $\ell^n$ map is \'{e}tale and therefore open. However a homomorphism of group schemes always has closed image, and so by connectedness of $H$ we conclude the result.

Since you know the answer to your last question in the case of an abelian variety $A$, I'll just treat the case of $H$. Now $k$ is algebraically closed, in particular perfect so we know that
$$ H \cong D \times U$$ 
where $D$ is a diagonalizable group and $U$ is unipotent. Any unipotent $U$ group over a perfect field has a filtration with successive quotients isomorphic to $\mathbf{G}_a$. Therefore if $(\ell,p) = 1$ (as is the case here), $U[\ell^n] = 0$ and so
$$H[\ell^n] \cong D[\ell^n].$$
In particular, we may assume that $H$ is connected diagonalizable and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbf{G}_m^q$ for some $q \in \mathbf{N}$ (there are no forms of $\mathbf{G}_m^q$ over an algebraically closed field). Hence
$$\mathbf{G}_m^q[\ell^n] \cong (\mu_{\ell^n})^q$$
which has order $\ell^{nq}$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Now I am more interseted in removing your assumption of being finite type or prime to the characterestic.